# Automake: Run a script before traversing subdirectories

Tags: automake

I have a build system setup for a library using the GNU autotools.  The library has subdirectories for source and header files.  It also contains a script in the top directory which auto-generates a source and header file (not the same as the config file) in the appropriate subdirectories.  It is necessary that these files are generated before make is performed in the subdirectories.

What is the simplest way to have the script run before subdirectories are traversed (i.e. when user calls `make`, the script is ran before traversing  `SUBDIRS`)?  I have tried adding rules like `all-local` with no success.

EDIT:

Top-level directory:

```
configure.ac    Makefile.am    src    include    myscript.sh
```

`Makefile.am`:

```
EXTRA_DIST = myscript.sh
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4

SUBDIRS = src include

.PHONY: gen-script

gen-script:
  ./myscript.sh
```

`src/Makefile.am`:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/include
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmylib.la
libmylib_la_SOURCES = \
  file1.cxx \
  file2.cxx \
  autogen-file.cxx

clean-local:
  rm -f autogen-file.cxx
```

`include/Makefile.am`:

```
nobase_include_HEADERS = \
  file1.h \
  file2.h \
  autogen-file.h

clean-local:
  rm -f autogen-file.h
```

Comment: I have added a bit of context to my setup.  The dependencies are explicit in the sub Makefiles.  The files are removed upon a clean, and thus need to be regenerated if a subsequent `make` is called

Comment: Thank you, it is clear to me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best solution would be to get rid of the recursive `make` and only have the top-level `Makefile.am`. Then you'd simply add a rule

```
include/autogen-file.h src/autogen-file.cxx: myscript.sh
    ${SHELL} $<
```

and list `include/autogen-file.h` in [`BUILT_SOURCES`](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Sources.html#Sources).

If you want to keep your recursive structure (even if this is [*considered harmful*](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)), you could place the rule to generate the files into the `Makefile.am`s in the sub-directories.

In `src/Makefile.am`:

```
autogen-file.cxx: ../myscript.sh
    cd ${top_srcdir} && ${SHELL} myscript.sh
```

And in `include/Makefile.am`:

```
autogen-file.h: ../myscript.sh
    cd ${top_srcdir} && ${SHELL} myscript.sh
```

By the way, how often do you need to re-build those? If the generated files only depend on the project configuration, you could simply run `myscript.sh` at the end of your `configure.ac` and delete the generated files only on `make distclean`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  One thing to note is that if a recursive structure is used, the auto-gen files must be the first ones in the `*_SOURCES` and `*_HEADERS` variables.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is force the current directory to run before the rest of the subdirectories with

```
SUBDIRS = . src include
```

More seriously, though, you should not use recursive automake. Particularly if your structure is relatively simple as it seems to be. If you have interests in looking up how to do that you can see my documentation on [Autotools Mythbuser](https://autotools.io/automake/nonrecursive.html).