# How to setup autotools for glib-compile-resources?

Tags: gtk, autotools

How would I setup my `Makefile.am` file to run `glib-compile-resources` to compile resources.

This is how my `Makefile.am` currently looks like:

```
INTLTOOL_FILES = intltool-extract.in \
                 intltool-merge.in \
                 intltool-update.in

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

SUBDIRS = src data po gnome pixmaps dicfiles

EXTRA_DIST = COPYING rpm/gjiten.spec scripts/make_debs scripts/make_release\
         intltool-extract.in intltool-merge.in intltool-update.in


DISTCLEANFILES = ${INTLTOOL_FILES} \
                 po/.intltool-merge-cache

MAINTAINERCLEANFILES += configure config.sub config.guess aclocal.m4 compile \
      depcomp install-sh \
      ${DISTCLEANFILES} intltool-extract intltool-merge intltool-update.in \
        ltmain.sh missing mkinstalldirs config.h.in po/*stamp* *stamp*
```

Or do I have to setup the commands within autogen.h or configure.ac ?

Comment: Generally, you should not explicitly name Autotools-generated files in `CLEANFILES`, `DISTCLEANFILES`, or `MAINTAINERCLEANFILES`.  Automake knows about these already, and will clean them where appropriate.  It also knows which files should not be cleaned at all, and you have put some of those on your `MAINTAINERCLEAN` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I setup my `Makefile.am` file to run `glib-compile-resources` to compile resources.

There are lots of ways, but the one I would recommend to you is to [add an `all-local` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html).  For example:

```
all-local:
        glib-compile-resources
```

You would also want to be sure to provide for cleaning the generated files, which might be accomplished either by adding them to `CLEANFILES` or by adding a `clean-local` target with an appropriate recipe.

Comment: I also needed to force the top-level directory to be processed first by using `SUBDIRS = . src data po gnome pixmaps dicfiles`  (advice taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34957591/6702598 ). Perhaps you could add that to your answer?

Comment: No, I think not, as any need for such a step is characteristic of project details that are not presented in the question.  I am satisfied that the comment you have already provided serves as a sufficient advisory.